# html to video transcoding for DLNA player (smartTV)

Tags: html, video

any method/softwares to transcode html to video on the fly and stream it to multiple DLNA player ( smartTV )?

the only way i think is to hook up a pc on each smartTV and open up the web.. unfortunately my smartTV  does not support web browser.. i hve considered by hooking the pc but im looking for other alternatives.

off record, i am new to this site and greeting to all the community.

Comment: update : i can use VLC to stream desktop to file then use PS3 media server to stream that file.. it is not the ideal solution but it works.. albeit a little slow..